# Creating a calculated field in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create to create 2 calculated fields in my Pandas DataFrame. The structure is as follows:

```
Index    aa    aw    ba    bw    wv     a_total    b_total
1        0     0     141   0     0
2        0    45.12   0    0    90.50
3        0     0      0   2857   893
```

I am trying to create two calculated columns (a_total & b_total) that calculate the columns of the dataframe for each row. I need the output to be determined by the values of the columns and the if logic listed below.

```
def calc_b():
if wv == 0:
    return ba

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)<wv:
    return ba

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw>wv):
    return ba+bw-wv

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw<wv):
    return ba

def calc_a():
if wv == 0:
    return aa

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)<wv:
    return aa

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw>wv):
    return aa+aw

if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw<wv):
    return aa+aw-abs(bw-wv)
```

In the example data provided above, the output columns would be:

```
Index    aa    aw    ba    bw    wv     a_total    b_total
1        0     0     141   0     0         0         141
2        0    45.12   0    0    90.50      0          0
3        0     0      0   2857   893       0         1964
```

I have also tried using if/elif statements and defining each outcome in boolean. The issue I ran into there is that as soon as one of the rows is determined it applies that calculation to the entire dataframe.

Just wanted to see what I might be missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Just clarified, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make it very easy to understand what the function is supposed to do, so I supposed most of it and fixed the issues I found. First of all, be careful with identation, which is really important in Python.

Second, wv, ba, bw, aa and aw variables weren't declared in the functions (at least as far as you showed us), so I attributed each one of them to a single value in the column, which I got as a result of an iteration through the dataframe index, setting the value of each cell in the last two columns individually.

If I supposed everything right, this little guy should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def calc_b(df, each):
    wv = df.loc[each, 'wv']
    ba = df.loc[each, 'ba']
    bw = df.loc[each, 'bw']
    aa = df.loc[each, 'aa']
    aw = df.loc[each, 'aw']
    if wv == 0:
        return ba

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)<wv:
        return ba

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw>wv):
        return ba+bw-wv

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw<wv):
        return ba

def calc_a(df, each):
    wv = df.loc[each, 'wv']
    ba = df.loc[each, 'ba']
    bw = df.loc[each, 'bw']
    aa = df.loc[each, 'aa']
    aw = df.loc[each, 'aw']
    if wv == 0:
        return aa

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)<wv:
        return aa

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw>wv):
        return aa+aw

    if wv>0 and (aw+bw)>wv and (bw<wv):
        return aa+aw-abs(bw-wv)  

#just a provisory quick df declaration
#df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(3, 5)),columns=['aa','aw','ba','bw', 'wv'])

for each in df.index.tolist():
    df.loc[each, 'a_total'] = calc_a(df, each)
    df.loc[each, 'b_total'] = calc_b(df, each)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Helena. I had originally defined the variables outside of the functions. Your example took care of the issue. I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problems! Just pay your tributes to the Gods of Python!

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.select`. Avoid loops at all costs

```
b_conditions = [df.wv == 0, 
               (df.wv>0) & ((df.aw+df.bw) < df.wv),
               (df.wv>0) & ((df.aw+df.bw)>df.wv) & (df.bw>df.wv),
               (df.wv>0) & ((df.aw+df.bw)>df.wv) & (df.bw<df.wv)]

b_choices = [df.ba, df.ba, df.ba + df.bw - df.wv, df.ba]
```

Then,

```
df['b_total'] = np.select(condlist=b_conditions,
                          choicelist=b_choices)
```

Similarly,

```
a_conditions = [df.wv == 0, 
               (df.wv>0) & (df.aw+df.bw) < df.wv,
               (df.wv>0) & ((df.aw+df.bw)>df.wv) & (df.bw>df.wv),
               (df.wv>0) & ((df.aw+df.bw)>df.wv) & (df.bw<df.wv)]

a_choices = [df.aa, df.aa, df.aa + df.aw, df.aa+df.aw-abs(df.bw-df.wv)]
```

Then,

```
df['a_total'] = np.select(condlist=a_conditions,
                          choicelist=a_choices)
```